# How to Pass the URLRequest in Moya

Tags: ios, swift, moya

In my Application, I'm using [Moya](https://github.com/Moya/Moya) to make the Api request. Here, I'm having URLRequest but I don't know how to pass it in MoyaProvider.

Alamofire Ex:

```
Alamofire.request(urlRequest)
```

Like the Same, I need to implement using [Moya](https://github.com/Moya/Moya) instead of using TargetApi.

Comment: Are you planning to make more explicit call with moya or just simple things

Comment: check the following answer

But you might have to make some changes as per your url and request type

Comment: Even Moya built on top of Alamofire, you're still shouldn't use Alamofire api directly. @HarshalBhavsar gave a right answer to you.

Answer (score 1):

After looking into the following article

[Writing Network Layer with Moya for Swift](https://medium.com/@vsemenchenko/writing-network-layer-with-moya-for-swift-3aa039a6e693)

I can say following code should work for you.

```
import Foundation
import Moya

enum MyServerAPI {
    case cameras
    case settingsFor(cameraId: String)

    // MARK: - User
    case createUser(email: String, password: String)
}

// 2:
extension MyServerAPI: TargetType {

    // 3:
    var baseURL: URL { return URL(string: "https://testing.myserver.com/api/v1")! }

    // 4:
    var path: String {
        switch self {
        case .cameras:
            return "/cameras"
        case .settingsFor(let cameraId):
            return "/cameras/\(cameraId)/settings"
        case .createUser:
            return "/user"
        }
    }

    // 5:
    var method: Moya.Method {
        switch self {
        case .createUsr:
            return .post
        default:
            return .get
        }
    }

    // 6:
    var parameters: [String: Any]? {
        switch self {
        case .createUser(let email, let password):
            var parameters = [String: Any]()
            parameters["email"] = email
            parameters["password"] = password
            return parameters
        default:
            return nil
        }
    }

    // 7:
    var parameterEncoding: ParameterEncoding {
        return JSONEncoding.default
    }

    // 8:
    var sampleData: Data {
        return Data()
    }

    // 9:
    var task: Task {
        return .request
    }
}


let provider = MoyaProvider<MyServerAPI>()
provider.request(.cameras) { (result) in
    switch result {
        case .success(let response):
            // do something with resoinse
        case .failure(let error):
            // show error
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`Moya` is working on `Alamofire` and hidden it realization. So the is no any reason to use Moya in your case. You can just use Alamofire by it-self if you need it.

The is no correct way to pass URLRequest to `Moya`. Only way is to download source code and add needed functionality by yourself